# How to save a int with SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, xml, sharedpreferences, android

I looked up a lot of tutorials on how to save int variables, but I  couldn't find good example for me. My code looks like this:

```
package com.example.countryclicker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; 
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    int exp,level,count,totalCount;
    Button mainButton;
    TextView current,total;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        current = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TcurrentCount);
        total =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TtotalCount);
        mainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                count+=1;
                current.setText("Your current count is "+ count);
                totalCount = count;
                total.setText("Your total count is " + totalCount);
            }
        });
    }  


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So, I have an integer counter, which increases everytime I click a button, but I want that whenever that user clicks that button,a program saves a value to some other integer and that value would still remain even if users closes an app.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you need to do is :

- when you click the button, get the int value from the shared preferences first, it if does not exist, create it
- increment the value by one
- save this value to the SharedPreferences again

So it would translate to something like that:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int totalCount = mySharedPreferences.getInt("INT_KEY", -1);
    if(totalCount == -1) {
       totalCount = 0; //initialize the total count value to 0
    }
    count += 1;
    totalCount += 1;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("INT_KEY", totalCount);
    editor.commit();
    current.setText("Your current count is "+ count);
    total.setText("Your total count is " + totalCount);
}
```

For more efficiency, get the `totalCount` value from the `SharedPreferences` when you start the app and save it to the `SharedPreferences` before you finish your activity.

You can read the android doc of the `SharedPreferences` class for more informations.

Comment: I get error at line at 
 totalCount = pref.getInt("INT_KEY", totalCount);
or
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

Comment: It doesnt specify, just a runtime error, in eclipse it's all right

Comment: Well, and what is this error? It has a stacktrace, so what does it say?

Comment: 10-30 10:10:37.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1216): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.content.SharedPreferences.getInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
10-30 10:10:37.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):  at com.example.countryclicker_v2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
10-30 10:10:37.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1216):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)

Comment: Did you initialize `pref`?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code inside your `onClick()` method for your button.

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity()
                                .getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("variableName", count);
    editor.commit();
```